# Angular 9 Component not being recognized in a module

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular9, angular-module

I've got a Component x along with its relevant html and scss files but i wanted to isolate it out with its own module.  However the selector defined in my new component isnt available to me if i try and reference it anywhere in my app,  My understanding is i can create a new module and import it into my app.module and it would effectively act as an extension of the original app.module :

Currently I get a note in my editor telling me:

> Component 'XComponent' is not included in a module and will not be available inside a template. Consider adding it to a NgModule declaration.

However thats what i was under the impression I was doing by exporting it from the new module and importing that module into the app.module

x.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  ViewEncapsulation,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy,
} from '@angular/core';

import { XService } from './x.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-x',
  templateUrl: 'x.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['x.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class XComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() id: string;
  private element: any;

  constructor(private xService: XService, private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    }
}
```

x.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class XService {

}
```

x.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { XComponent } from './x.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [XComponent],
  exports: [XComponent],
})
export class XModule {}
```

and finally I import my new module in my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './core/header/header.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';


import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { XModule } from './shared/x';

const epRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(epRoutes), XModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: At first glance this looks good and should work fine..?

Comment: Unless you’re trying to use app-x in another (sibbling) module that we are not seeing here?

Comment: Code seems fine. Sometimes restarting the server fixes the module import issues. Can you please show up where the <app-x> is being used?

Comment: @MikeOne Unfortunately not the only two modules in my app thus far are the two referenced.

Comment: ok, it has started working... for no apparent reason.  Thanks for double checking my work chaps. Should I delete this q then I guess? or maybe leave it as reference for what works? hmm

Comment: what do you do? I got same issues